# Flag a node programatically

Tags: commerce, flags

I am trying to get flag "purchase" and flag it for an user while completing an order in Rules (Commerce). This is how it goes in a PHP code:

```
$flag = flag_get_flag('purchase');
$nid = $_SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'];
$nid = explode("node/", $nid);
$node = node_load($nid[1]);
global $user;
$flag->flag('purchase', $node->nid, user_load($user->uid), TRUE);
```

Does anybody see any inaccuracy in what I've done? I just don't know why it is not working.

This is the error I am getting (actually it says nothing to me):

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in eval() (line 4 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in eval() (line 6 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sites\all\modules\rules\modules\php.eval.inc(146) : eval()'d code).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in flag_entity->applies_to_entity() (line 130 of C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\sites\all\modules\flag\includes\flag\flag_entity.inc).

Comment: This suggests that the flag is undefined. Are you sure the machine name of the flag is "purchase"? Check again..

Comment: @pritywiz that's incorrect. The error is the code fetching the $nid is invalid, hence $nid[1] is undefined and the node isn't loaded.

Comment: How is the node id defined at that point? Are you on a node page? If on checkout complete (e.g checkout/12/complete), the nid won't be available that way.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right @DavidThomas. So what can I do then?

Comment: You will need to try to get the product display node id from the product reference field on the relevant line item. It's complicated by the fact that an order can contain multiple line items from different product displays and potentially that the same product may be referenced on multiple displays. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code... You can read node arguments using [arg](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function in Drupal...

```
global $user;
$flag = flag_get_flag('purchase');
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$flag->flag('purchase', $node->nid, user_load($user->uid), TRUE);
```

Comment: This code will definitely work when I find out how to get $node->nid of bought product. Thank you Anil.

Comment: Glad it worked.. If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation

Comment: It would work if the node nid was available, in this case, the node id isn't available that way.

Comment: I have used the same code, but for me 'uid' column is not getting updated in 'flagging' table. why it is happening?